# R - RPostgreSQL Package - dbWriteTable to non-default schema where target table contains more fields than dataframe

Tags: r, postgresql, schema, rpostgresql

### The Issue

I am attempting to copy the contents of an R dataframe `df` to a PostgreSQL table `table_name` located in schema `schema_name`. By default, PostgreSQL will write tables to the `public` schema and I **do not** want to change this setting. The two unique aspects of this transfer are:

1. Writing to a table under a non-default schema; and
2. The dataframe `df` contains a fewer number of fields than `table_name`. **All** the fields contained in `df`, however, do exist in `table_name`.

### What I've Tried

I first attempted to use `dbWriteTable` from the `RPostgreSQL` package by using a workaround:

`dbWriteTable(con, c("schema_name","table_name"), df, append = T)`

resulting in the following exception:

```
Error in postgresqlgetResult(new.con) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  missing data for column "extra_col"
CONTEXT:  COPY df, line 1: " [removed contents] "
```

I then attempted to us `dbWriteTable2` from the `caroline` package (a wrapper for the aforementioned `dbWriteTable` function), but the non-default schema hack employed above does not appear to work:

`dbWriteTable2(con, c("schema_name","table_name"), df, append = T, add.id = FALSE)`

creates the following exception:

```
creating NAs/NULLs for for fields of table that are missing in your df 
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  relation "schema_name" does not exist 
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM schema_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What about SQL `insert` statements, looping over rows ?

Comment: That's likely my fallback option if I can't get the above to work, but I'd rather avoid that since this is being done for multiple dataframes/tables, some of which are fairly large.

Comment: And why not adding the missing null fields before the query ? df$extr_col1 <- NA ; df$extr_col2 <- NA ;... then dbWriteTable() ?

Comment: Used a variation of this in the end. Thanks! Would still, however, be interested in a direct solution to the issue.

Comment: I add that as an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the missing null fields before the query :

```
df$extr_col1 <- NA
df$extr_col2 <- NA
...
```

then run your original `dbWriteTable()`...